# Introductory learning resources for .Net globalisation/localisation

Tags: .net, localization, globalization

I am trying to find some good articles for .Net developers on how to ensure Winforms apps work correctly for non-English users. Articles explaining potential pitfalls and advice on how to test for these pitfalls would be perfect - but I haven't yet found any yet.

Areas I am most interest in are: decimal amounts, Dates and setting file permissions for builtin Windows accounts.

So if you have any links like these handy, I'll be very grateful if you would share them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an introductory course on what i18n, L10n and g11n actually is, I have to recommend reading [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735615837):

[image: Developing International Software by Dr. International, Microsoft Press 2003]

Although it is quite outdated in terms of API, it is great way to start learning this topic. There is also a MSDN [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/drintl/) by the author of this book.

I haven't read it, so I couldn't recommend it, but there is also a book dedicated specifically to [.Net Internationalization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321341384):

[image: .Net Internationalization by Guy Smith-Ferrier, Addison-Wesley Professional 2006]

[Oren A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424952/oren-a) already gave you a link to MSDN, but I found this documentation both incomplete and hard to understand, especially for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6270d0z.aspx) is pretty good and broad enough to answer your question.